# log cpu time, peak mem etc for cronjobs

Tags: php, profiling, monitoring, cron

I have a rather large number of cronjobs on a webserver that are ran with varying levels of niceness.

It appears that some of them are requiring an unexpected number of CPU cycles on the test database. Of course, I can see what jobs rant at 16:30, but due to the number of crons, my task would be much easier if I had a log like this:

```
Dec 19 02:13:09  /var/crons/cron1  [user cpu time used]  [system cpu time used]  [peak mem]  ..
```

Is there a utility that I could just add before the crontab, like so:

```
*/6 * * * * nice -n 18 getrusage?? /usr/bin/php /var/crons/cron1 > /var/log/something
```

Maybe something related to `getrusage(2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call [`getrusage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) from PHP, so maybe this idea is workable: instead of calling /usr/bin/php from the crontab, invoke a wrapper that calls getrusage before and after calling the actual PHP script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$fh = fopen("/var/log/cronusage.log", "a");
fputs($fh, "Executing " . $_SERVER['argv'][1] . "\n");
fputs($fh, "BEFORE\n");
foreach (getrusage() as $k => $v) {
    fputs($fh, "$k -> $v\n");
}
fclose($fh);

$_SERVER['argv'][0] = '/usr/bin/php';
// FIXME Attention args not escaped possible security vuln.
system(join(' ', $_SERVER['argv']));

$fh = fopen("/var/log/cronusage.log", "a");
fputs($fh, "AFTER\n");
foreach (getrusage() as $k => $v) {
    fputs($fh, "$k -> $v\n");
}
fputs($fh, "\n");
fclose($fh);
?>
```

It's not tested, just an idea.

The `time(1)` command might also be useful for this purpose.